# Is installing Ubuntu on Mac as simple as installing on a generic PC?

Tags: installation, hardware, macbook

I am planning to buy a new laptop and as I'm an Ubuntu Fanatic. I'd like to know whether the procedure of installing Ubuntu on a Mac is as simple and straight-forward as it is on a PC. If it is then I'll go with Mac otherwise I'll stick to Lenovo.

Comment: I had once installed Ubuntu on a MacBook PRO at work and fond it hard to set it up in a power-saving way.The result was, that the MACBook ran 8 hrs with Mac OS and 3 hrs with Ubuntu.On my Opinion you should either head for the Lenovo, or, if you like MAC, just use MAC OS, which is not too bad.And as it is a Unix derivate many thinks work similar deep inside and many software can be simply compiled for MAC.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Was it a smooth installing experience or did you face any issues?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on which Mac you want and what version of Ubuntu you want to install on it. Take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook for more information. There you can find exactly what works and what doesnt work on specific MacBooks

Comment: Thanks, I'm planning for MacBook Pro 7,1 and Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: hmm..the link you pasted gives a pretty easy way of installing. Looks like I could have the best of both the worlds! Thanks alot for sharing!

Answer (score 7):

Latest compatibility information can be found at [Ubuntu Friendly](https://friendly.ubuntu.com/), a site that syndicates user-submitted hardware test data. [As of Ubuntu 11.10](https://friendly.ubuntu.com/?stars=1&release=4&popularity=any&term=apple+mac) it looks like Macbooks run pretty well with Ubuntu with the exception of poor suspend/resume support, which knocks down their rating considerably.

Comment: Regarding the suspend/resume on Mac laptops, upgrading to 12.04 fixed that issue for me.  No hardware problems from the upgrade either, so I consider it a success :)